# Piping stdout to stdin of another process in node.js

Tags: node.js, pipe, stdin

I'm new to node.js and trying to execute two processes in a row, the first process' stdout piped into the second's stdin. And then the second process' stdout should be piped into variable res as the response to a URL request. Code is here. Part of it is written by someone else so maybe I have misunderstanding:

```
  var sox = spawn("sox", soxArgs)
  var rubberband = spawn("rubberband", rubberbandArgs)

  sox.stdout.pipe(rubberband.stdin)

  rubberband.stdout.pipe(res) #won't send to res anything, why?
  #rubberband.stdin.pipe(res) won't send to res anything, either!
  #sox.stdout.pipe(res) will work just fine

  sox.stdin.write(data)     
  sox.stdin.end() 
  #the actual sox process will not execute until sox.stdin is filled with data..?
```

Any help would be appreciated! I've spent hours looking into this!

Comment: Did you look at the docs?

Comment: @Nirk I read http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options but not sure if that addresses my question. Any thoughts?

Comment: Would also appreciate some useful methods to debug this thing..

Comment: Read http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_child_process_spawn_command_args_options -- it gives a complete example of `ps ax | grep ssh`

Comment: I am a bit confused which one runs first and for which one do you need the output in response.

Comment: @user568109 Sox is the first process, rubberband the second. Yes the setup is a little weird as sox doesn't execute until the very last line. But I can be wrong on this.

Comment: Looks like Sox is working as expected but rubberband is not. Are you sure that the rubberband processes the input from stdin and not from some file passed it to it in the argument. If it reads its own input other than what it is given to it, this will not work.

Answer (score 8):

I think the solution you are looking for is piping stdin to stdout from https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin :

```js
process.stdin.on('readable', () => {
  const chunk = process.stdin.read();
  if (chunk !== null) {
    process.stdout.write(`data: ${chunk}`);
  }
});

process.stdin.on('end', () => {
  process.stdout.write('end');
});
```